# Looking for hints on the below 3D geometry problem.

Tags: vectors, 3d, solid-geometry

Planes are drawn so as to make an angle $60 ^\circ$ with the line $x = y = z$ and the angle of $45^\circ$ with the line $x=0=y-z$. Show that all these planes make an angle $60^\circ$ with the plane $x=0$.

I am assuming the required plane be of the form $ax+by+cz=d$ and Looking for hints to proceed further. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would help if you could provide a diagram

Comment: @XcoderX my apologies, this is all that I have.

Comment: Try https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/

Comment: @XcoderX: I dont think that site is helping me plot the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{n}(a,b,c)$ be a vector normal of the plane.

Thus,
$$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{|a+b+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt3}$$ and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\frac{|b+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt2}$$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
We obtain:
$$3|b+c|=2|a+b+c|,$$ which gives
$$3(b+c)=2(a+b+c)$$ or
$$b+c=2a$$ or
$$a+b+c=3a,$$ which gives
$$|a+b+c|=3|a|$$ and indeed,
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}.$$
Also, we have
$$3(b+c)=-2(a+b+c)$$ or
$$5(a+b+c)=3a$$ or
$$5|a+b+c|=3|a|,$$ which gives
$$\frac{5}{2}=\frac{|a|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}},$$
which is impossible.

Done!